# Move tab from one column to another in Sublime Text using only keys

Tags: sublimetext2, text-editor, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Does anyone know this shortcut? I'm looking for it online, but I can't seem to find it

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To move it is <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> to move to Group 0, <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> to Group 1, and so on - that's on Linux, Windows, and OSX.

Text buffers can also be moved to their neighbouring groups:

- Linux, Windows:

  - <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>LEFT</kbd>
  - <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>RIGHT</kbd>
- OSX

  - <kbd>SUPER</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>SUPER</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>LEFT</kbd>
  - <kbd>SUPER</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>SUPER</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>RIGHT</kbd>

Here's the whole group section of my `Default (Linux).sublime-keymap` - the Windows keys are all exactly the same, while the OSX keys are the same in the top section but differ in the bottom section, below where I have placed an explanatory comment.

```
// The keys BELOW are for Linux, Windows, and OSX.

{ "keys": ["ctrl+1"], "command": "focus_group", "args": { "group": 0 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+2"], "command": "focus_group", "args": { "group": 1 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+3"], "command": "focus_group", "args": { "group": 2 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+4"], "command": "focus_group", "args": { "group": 3 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+5"], "command": "focus_group", "args": { "group": 4 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+6"], "command": "focus_group", "args": { "group": 5 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+7"], "command": "focus_group", "args": { "group": 6 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+8"], "command": "focus_group", "args": { "group": 7 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+9"], "command": "focus_group", "args": { "group": 8 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+1"], "command": "move_to_group", "args": { "group": 0 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+2"], "command": "move_to_group", "args": { "group": 1 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+3"], "command": "move_to_group", "args": { "group": 2 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+4"], "command": "move_to_group", "args": { "group": 3 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+5"], "command": "move_to_group", "args": { "group": 4 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+6"], "command": "move_to_group", "args": { "group": 5 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+7"], "command": "move_to_group", "args": { "group": 6 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+8"], "command": "move_to_group", "args": { "group": 7 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+9"], "command": "move_to_group", "args": { "group": 8 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+0"], "command": "focus_side_bar" },

// The keys BELOW are for Linux and Windows only.
//
// The OSX keys all use 'super' instead of 'ctrl'.
//
// e.g. In the top command use: ["super+k", "super+up"]
// e.g. In the bottom command use: ["super+k", "super+shift+right"]

{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+up"], "command": "new_pane" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+shift+up"], "command": "new_pane", "args": {"move": false} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+down"], "command": "close_pane" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+left"], "command": "focus_neighboring_group", "args": {"forward": false} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+right"], "command": "focus_neighboring_group" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+shift+left"], "command": "move_to_neighboring_group", "args": {"forward": false} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+shift+right"], "command": "move_to_neighboring_group" },
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean rearranging the tabs within the same group, there's a good plugin called [MoveTab](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/MoveTab)

My keybindings `Sublime Text --> Preferences --> Key Bindings (User) -->`

```
{
    "keys": ["super+alt+shift+["],
    "command": "move_tab",
    "args": { "position": "-1" }
},
{
    "keys": ["super+alt+shift+]"],
    "command": "move_tab",
    "args": { "position": "+1" }
}
```

**Allows `CMD+Shift+Option+[` and `CMD+Shift+Option+]`**

---

If you have [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) you can install via `CMD+Shift+P --> Install Package --> MoveTab`

Answer (score 1):

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class DualViewMoveTo(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
            self.window.run_command('set_layout', { "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0], "rows": [0.0, 1.0], "cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]] })
            self.window.run_command('focus_group', { "group": 0 })
            self.window.run_command('move_to_group', { "group": 1 })
```

Comment: This would be better with some explanatory text!

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent plugin offered by Sublime Text itself called [Origami](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Origami), it allows you to create new panes(Columns), delete panes, move and clone views(Tabs) from pane to pane. You can easily shift tabs between a split view using this plugin. Also if you just reorder the tabs in a single pane then Sublime Text offers another good plugin called [Move​Tab](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/MoveTab).